# Difference between Ctrl K + D and Ctrl k + F

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the difference between the Visual Studio shortcuts "Ctrl K + D"
   and "Ctrl K + F" ?

Comment: By default: Format Document vs Format Selection. The former formats the entire document and the latter formats only what you've selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ctrl K+D    :   Format document to code formatting settings

Ctrl K+F    :   Format selection to code formatting settings

To find complete list of shortcuts,refer to this link
https://shortcutworld.com/Visual-Studio/win/Visual-Studio_2015_Shortcuts

Hope This helps !!